# Slow to do and slow in doing

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

Is there a difference between "slow ( or quick) to do something" and slow ( or quick) in doing something? Various dictionaries list both uses but don't make any remarks as to their usages. 
Do they imply different things?

- [My boss is always slow to tell us about changes in the schedule.
  -](https://www.google.ro/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/slow_1)
- [They’re usually pretty slow in returning my phone calls.](https://www.google.ro/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/slow_1)
- [She wasn't slow to realize what was going on.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/slow_1)
- [His poetry was slow in achieving recognition.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/slow_1)

Comment: Extremely similar. I feel the infinitive form might sound ever so slightly more formal, but even that may be subjective.

Answer (score -2):

It is a minor difference. It has nothing to do with slow or quick, the difference is between the infinitive form of the verb and the present perfect progressive form.

`Present perfect progressive tense describes an action that began in the past, continues in the present, and may continue into the future.`

So the first sentence is a general statement. The second is about an action happening.

The difference is very subtle, and in most situations there is probably no difference at all.